# How to retrieve redirect url from http server.?

Tags: java

I am getting 200 as a response code instead of 3xx when I perform HTTP post request, even though web page gets redirected automatically. I tried [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-httpurlconnection-follow-redirect-example/), but dosen't work. My code:

```
HttpURLConnection con = getMultipartHttpURLConnection(
        formParameter.getServerUrl(), boundary);
setRequestHeaders(con);
String urlParameters = getParameter(formParameter.getForm());
// Send post request
con.setDoOutput(true);
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
wr.flush();
wr.close();
responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
String header = con.getHeaderField("Location");
```

**Edit:**

By some  research I find out that if server is configured to redirect to `https://` enabled url, then I am getting `3xx` as response code, otherwise not. Example given in the link above does the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `HttpURLConnection` is smart and handles the redirection internally. The `200` response code is the response code of the new location to which the redirection happened.

The only way that I am aware of how you could retrieve the redirection URL is to use `setFollowRedirects(false)` and follow the redirection manually.

See the following example:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class GetRedirectURL {
    public static void main(final String... args) throws IOException {
        final URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com/");
        //HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
        final HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        //con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        final int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        final String location = con.getHeaderField("Location");
        System.err.format("%d%n%s%n", responseCode, location);
    }
}
```

If you leave this code unmodified, it will print `200 null`. If you uncomment any of the lines controlling the redirection behavior, the output changes to `200 http://www.google...' .

It's important that modifying the redirection settings is done before the statemachine of the `HttpURLConnection` instance is, by method calls that read from the response, to send the request.

Comment: Ok,but how to read the redirection url and how to check whether redirection url  exists or not.

Comment: See the edit that I just made, I forgot the original question because it wasn't repeated in the text.

Comment: i tried both connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true); 
   HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true); and both dosen't helped. Please check the link that i edited in question.

Comment: Did you use `true` or `false` as value? It needs to be `false`, but in your comment you write `true`.

Comment: I tried using both true/false but that too dosen't make the difference.

Comment: Okay. I updated my answer with a corresponding code example and a little bit of explanation. If you are still facing the same problem, you could update your code example in the question where you tried to insert the redirect control.

Comment: It works.Actually we need to put HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false); above
final HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();